# json_decode: get specific entry out of a list of objects with same name

Tags: php, arrays, json

Here's my input JSON

```
    {
        "artist":{
           "#text":"Radical Face",
           "mbid":"6c25514f-1f14-4106-a142-be95ba11f117"
        },
        "name":"Let the River In",
        "streamable":"1",
        "mbid":"fd4c8c63-2cb4-4282-87cd-a75a332f64ba",
        "album":{
           "#text":"Ghost",
           "mbid":"c5c64ec1-3271-4461-92ea-3727cdc71995"
        },
        "url":"http:\/\/www.last.fm\/music\/Radical+Face\/_\/Let+the+River+In",
        "image":[
           {
              "#text":"http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/34s\/3996573.jpg",
              "size":"small"
           },
           {
              "#text":"http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/64s\/3996573.jpg",
              "size":"medium"
           },
           {
              "#text":"http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/126\/3996573.jpg",
              "size":"large"
           },
           {
              "#text":"http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/300x300\/3996573.jpg",
              "size":"extralarge"
           }
        ],
        "date":{
           "#text":"5 Jun 2013, 17:57",
           "uts":"1370455055"
        }
     },
```

I extract data from it with

```
$tracks=$data['track'];

foreach ($tracks as $track) {
$artist = $track['artist']['#text'];
$title = $track['name'];
$url = $track['url'];
...
}
```

... which work. Now my question is: how can I get the medium thumbnail given that they're all under 'image'->'#text' ? Each one has another entry (together with '#text'), which specifies the size ('image'->'size'), but how can I get the medium thumb url?

Comment: Loop through it, check where `size == medium`, use that entry. There are many ways to disguise that procedure, but that's what you need.

Comment: Something like `if ($track['image']['size'] == medium) { $thumb = $track['image']['#text']; }` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$image = null;
foreach ($track['image'] as $i) {
    if ($i['size'] == 'medium') {
        $image = $i['#text'];
        break;
    }
}
```

or:

```
$image = array_reduce($track['image'], function ($image, array $i) { return $image ?: ($i['size'] == 'medium' ? $i['#text'] : null); });
```

or:

```
$image = array_filter($track['image'], function ($image) { return $image['size'] == 'medium'; });
$image = isset($image[0]['#text']) ? $image[0]['#text'] : null;
```

or:

```
$track['image'] = array_combine(
    array_map(function ($i) { return $i['size']; }, $track['image']),
    array_map(function ($i) { return $i['#text']; }, $track['image'])
);
$image = $track['image']['medium'];
```

etc. etc.

Comment: Working! :D
I'm marking this because it's the most complete answer. I voted up all working solutions though :)

Comment: Latest thing. I'm using the one line solution. When I use $image outside the foreach I always get the last entry in the json array. How can I get the latest ("top", not "bottom")?

Comment: ??? You mean `foreach (...) { $image = ...; } echo $image;` is always the *last* image that was assigned in the loop? Well, yes. If you want all results or the first result, save it into an array: `$images[] = ...; echo $image[0];`

Comment: Sorry for my post really not being clear.. I meant how to have $image returning just the first result. I'm trying to save the loop into an array as you said but what should I put in $images[] = ...; ?

Comment: ??? Still lost. Please open a new question for that.

Comment: Sorry :( Here you are http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949034/json-get-first-result-instead-of-last-one

Answer (score 1):

Inside your foreach loop, do another foreach over the image field

```
$thumbs = $track['image']
$medium = '';
foreach ($thumbs as $thumb) {
  if ($thumb['size'] == 'medium')
  {
    $medium = $thumb['#text']
    break;
  }
}
```