# JSON, get first result instead of last one

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a JSON with a lot of results which contains in the various "objects", also this one related to images.

```
"image":[
           {
              "#text":"http:\/\/BLAHBLAH",
              "size":"small"
           },
           {
              "#text":"http:\/\/BLAHBLAH",
              "size":"medium"
           },
           {
              "#text":"http:\/\/BLAHBLAH",
              "size":"large"
           }
        ]
```

With

```
$image = array_reduce($track['image'], function ($image, array $i) {
                 return $image ?: ($i['size'] == 'medium' ? $i['#text'] : null);
         });
```

I get the medium image URL, though when I do `echo $image` I get the image of the first result (chronologically) in the loop (so bottom of JSON)

How do I get the latest (chronologically) instead (first result at the top of the JSON)?

**EDIT:**
[Here](http://pastebin.com/f4nE87vc)'s the whole code.
Here's the link (you can see the relevant portion at the bottom right).

Comment: Unless you're not showing us your entire code, you're mismatching a parentheses. e.g. `(...)`.

Comment: Maybe try adding another `)` in `: null); });` thus, `: null); }));` ? Or is there something I don't know(`?`).

Comment: I added the whole code. P.S.: I tried to add another ) but I get 500 server error

Comment: Plus, I think the final entry in `"size":"large"`, doesn't need a comma, from what I've seen in other JSON stuff. I could very well be wrong.

Comment: With the whole code you can see also the json input. I need the medium image url but only for the result at the top of json. What I'm getting is the one at the bottom

Comment: ? Those entries in first post are a portion of the json input. Which now you can see as a whole

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand you are after the first one with a size == medium

Here is a function that will get it for you.

```
 function getTextForSize($array, $size = "medium") {
      foreach($array as $v){
         if ($v["size"] == $size){
              return $v["#text"];
         }
      }
 }
```

to use just say

```
 $text = getTextForSize($track["image"], "medium");
```

change the second argument if you want a different sized image.

If you are married to the array reduce method then try this out

```
$image = array_reduce($track['image'], function ($image, array $i) {
             return $image.((!$image) && $i['size'] == 'medium' ? $i['#text'] : null);
        }     
);
```

If you are after just the first element can simply do this.

```
 $track['image'][0]
```

if you wanted the text you would say

```
 $track['image'][0]['#text'];
```

for size it would be

```
 $track['image'][0]['size'];
```

Comment: It's probably giving the OP the error cuz I think he forgot to close his code with a `)`, from what I can tell by his posted code.

Comment: With the whole code you can see also the json input. I need the medium image url but only for the result at the top of json. What I'm getting is the one at the bottom

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno Are you after the first one where size matches medium?

Comment: Okay I didn't get that from the way the question was phrased.

Comment: Sorry.. I try to be clear but it's not always easy to explain :D

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno updated answer... hopefully this shows you some love.

Comment: Here's the JSON:
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=JtYvj4M9
Here's what I get with `<?php echo $track['image'][0]['#text']; ?>` (array reduce method): `http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34s/3996573.jpg` while I should get `http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64s/57090809.png` (first size medium image url from the top of the file)

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno What if you were to replace `[0]` by `[1]`, what results will you get? Since theoretically, `[0]` should be `small` and `[1]` being medium?

Comment: I updated the answer with a couple more alternatives approaches ... a [1] index would work so long as the medium photo was ALWAYS the second one in the list.

Comment: @Orangepill ah yes, of course. This falls in with the big `IF`.